# Firebase initializing error when trying to access database and auth

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an express server which will be used to communicate with the firebase database. However, I need to access the auth and database objects.

When I start the server, I get an error saying `firebase.auth()` is not a function. This is the same error I get when I try to access `firebase.database`

Any ideas?

[image: Firebase initializing on an express app]

Comment: If you're getting an error message, be sure to include that in your question.  And for backend code, you probably want to be using the Firebase Admin SDK instead of the client SDK.

Comment: So the logic to login, sign up users should be in my client app? Is that right?

Comment: You use the Firebase Auth client SDK to manage the login flow on the client for all supported platforms.  The FirebaseUI library makes this even easier.